# Is it possible to retrieve count of products from each category in an order using woocommerce and mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Newbie here, just like you've been once. I found the following code to retrieve all the product items from orders, but I'd like to also retrieve how many products of each parent-category there is in each order. I have 5 parent-categories with many sub-categories, but only the parent-category is interesting in this case.

Here's the code I've found:

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from www_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
from
    www_posts p 
join 
    www_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
join 
    www_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
where
    post_type = 'shop_order'
group by
    p.ID
```

Here's an example:

These are the columns in the order_items table:

```
order_item_id, order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id
```

And here are the rows for one order:

```
6, ProductName, line_item, 515
7, FreeShipping, shipping, 515
8, Tax-2, tax, 515
```

Here we see that someone bought something named "ProductName" with "FreeShipping" and with "Tax-2". That means she only bought 1 product. I tried to add

```
where oi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
```

and then in select

```
Select COUNT(oi.order_id)
```

like this:

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    (select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from www_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items,
    COUNT(oi.order_id)
from
    www_posts p 
join 
    www_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
join 
    www_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' and
    oi.order_item_type ='line_item'
group by
    p.ID
```

But in this example `COUNT(oi.order_id)` resulted in 52 when I expected only 1. And also, since I want to have the count of products for each category I understand that this is too complex for me to understand so far.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Incidentally, if the post_id comparison is always required then does it need to be part of the case?

Comment: @Strawberry Hey, I've now tried to explain my problem further. About if it's required, i do not think so, it's just some code i found here on stackoverflow. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I can only refer you again to my original comment.